# PHP ANDROID JSON strange error

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm calling this file from an Android application which is as follows but the application  crashes :

Here's the code:

```
    <?php
include("connection.php");
$src=$_POST['src'];
$dir=$_POST['tab'];
if($dir=="up")
    $tab="TRAINS";
else
    $tab="TRAIN";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tab." WHERE STATIONS LIKE '%".$src."%'";

//mysql_select_db($mysql_database);
$result = mysql_query($sql) 
or die(mysql_error());
$json = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))     
{

    $bus = array(
        'id' => $row['_id'],
        'trainname' => $row['TRAINNAME'],
        'stations' => $row['STATIONS'],
        'arrival'=>$row['ARRIVAL']
    );
    array_push($json, $bus);
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
//mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Logcat file :

```
    04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobisys.android.External_to_application/com.mobisys.android.External_to_application.ListTrainsFromSrc}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1728)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1747)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at com.mobisys.android.External_to_application.ListTrainsFromSrc.onCreate(ListTrainsFromSrc.java:71)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1692)
04-28 11:02:29.504: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     ... 11 more
```

The class from which the php file is called:
ListTrainsFrmSrc.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

//import com.mobisys.android.External_to_application.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class ListTrainsFromSrc extends Activity{
String res=null;
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TRAINNAME = "trainname";
private static final String TAG_STATIONS = "stations";
private static final String TAG_ARRIVAL = "arrival";
ArrayList<String> indexes=null;
ArrayList<String> Tables=null;
//String res=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);
    String[] tabdata=null;
    Time dtNow = new Time();
    dtNow.setToNow();
    int hours = dtNow.hour;
    int minutes = dtNow.minute;
    int time=hours*100+minutes;
    ArrayList<String> indexes=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Tables = new ArrayList<String>();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String product = i.getStringExtra("Station");
    String dir=i.getStringExtra("Dir");
    String url="http://hotelmanagement.hostoi.com/dinesh/onlysrc.php"; 
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2); 
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("src", product));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tab",dir));

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    final JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url,nameValuePair);
    try{
    for(int p = 0; p < json.length(); p++){
        JSONObject jobj = json.getJSONObject(p);

        // Storing each json item in variable
        String id = jobj.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = jobj.getString(TAG_TRAINNAME);
        String stations = jobj.getString(TAG_STATIONS);
        String arr = jobj.getString(TAG_ARRIVAL);

        String stn[]=stations.split(",");
        String arrt[]=arr.split(",");
        for(int j=0;j<stn.length;j++)
            {
                    if(stn[j].equals(product) && stn.length==arrt.length){
                        int start_time=Integer.parseInt(arrt[j]);
                        if(start_time>time){
                            indexes.add(id);
                            Tables.add(arrt[j]+"\t"+name);
                        }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        tabdata=Tables.toArray(new String[Tables.size()]);
        final int[] a = new int[indexes.size()];  
        int l = 0;  

        for (String integer : indexes)  
            a[l++] = Integer.parseInt(integer);  
        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tabdata);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

       listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListTrainDetails.class);
                    i.putExtra("trainID",a[position]);
                    i.putExtra("json",json.toString());

                    startActivity(i);
                }
              });

    }catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONArray jArray = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url,List<NameValuePair> nvp) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jArray;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you concatenate strings with the dot (.) operator, not with the + operator

so this line:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM "+$tab+" WHERE STATIONS LIKE '%"+src+"%"+$dest+"%'" ;`

should be like:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tab." WHERE STATIONS LIKE '%".src."%".$dest."%'" ;`

Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Try to stay away from mysql_ functions, and use PDO or at least mysqli

Comment: Oops ! Too much of java ! Thanks ! :)

Comment: Not a problem! Don't forget to mark the question as answered so that other people might find it helpful too.

Comment: Again a problem. I searched for this problem now : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%%' at line 1". Couldnt find anything because of the " %% " signs.

Comment: that means that the POST variables are empty. 
Try to put a die(print_r($_POST)) before making the connection and verify that the POST contents are being passed.

Comment: @DineshRamchandani It should be obvious but if you get "You have an error in your SQL synxax" I suggest that you log you SQL statements somewhere so that you can look at them and figure out what the problem is. Also, did you understand what Alan meant with "SQL injection" above? It is a pretty serious flaw in your code.

Comment: And by done i dont mean the application is working now. I changed mysql to mysqli. :D

Comment: You should also make sure you don't just pass whatever you get in your POST variables without proper escaping. Either automatically using a framework or by doing it yourself. Except for http://xkcd.com/327/ , SQL injections are bad. Being able to pass in bad data causing your server to do unexpected things or even output errors with other sensitive data is bad as well.

Comment: @DineshRamchandani if you're already using mysqli then make use of prepared statements, that way if you don't clean user input at least your code will be less vulnerable to SQL Injection, but XSS is still a possibility. You should always clean user input before inserting into a database.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, `.` is used to concatenate strings, not `+`. Using `+` adds them as numbers, and in this case the result is `0`. Therefore you are effectively running `mysql_query("0")`, which of course won't work.

Answer (score 0):

String Concatenation in PHP is done with a `.` not a `+`.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tab." WHERE STATIONS LIKE '%".src."%".$dest."%'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In php , you use concat a string as . (dot) operator , not (+ operator)

Change

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM "+$tab+" WHERE STATIONS LIKE '%"+src+"%"+$dest+"%'" ;
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tab." WHERE STATIONS LIKE '%".$src."%".$dest."%'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tab." WHERE STATIONS LIKE '".src."%".$dest."%'" ;
```